# Uncaught NetworkError: Failed to execute 'send' on 'XMLHttpRequest'

Tags: html, ajax, servlets

I need to display hello world using servlet program in browser by Ajax call but on clicking button I am not to display it what could be reason of this error:

> Uncaught NetworkError: Failed to execute 'send' on 'XMLHttpRequest': Failed to load 'file:///D:/workspace/Poc_Ajax/WebContent/WEB-INF/HelloWorld'.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function getXMLHttpRequest() {
    var xmlHttpReq = false;
    // to create XMLHttpRequest object in non-Microsoft browsers
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        xmlHttpReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
        try {
            // to create XMLHttpRequest object in later versions
            // of Internet Explorer
            xmlHttpReq = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
        } catch (exp1) {
            try {
                // to create XMLHttpRequest object in older versions
                // of Internet Explorer
                xmlHttpReq = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            } catch (exp2) {
                xmlHttpReq = false;
            }
        }
    }
    return xmlHttpReq;
}
/*
 * AJAX call starts with this function
 */
function makeRequest() {
    var xmlHttpRequest = getXMLHttpRequest();
    xmlHttpRequest.onreadystatechange = getReadyStateHandler(xmlHttpRequest);
    xmlHttpRequest.open("POST", "HelloWorld", true);
    xmlHttpRequest.setRequestHeader("Content-Type",
            "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xmlHttpRequest.send();
}

/*
 * Returns a function that waits for the state change in XMLHttpRequest
 */
function getReadyStateHandler(xmlHttpRequest) {

    // an anonymous function returned
    // it listens to the XMLHttpRequest instance
    return function() {
        if (xmlHttpRequest.readyState == 4) {
            if (xmlHttpRequest.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById("hello").innerHTML = xmlHttpRequest.responseText;
            } else {
                alert("HTTP error " + xmlHttpRequest.status + ": " + xmlHttpRequest.statusText);
            }
        }
    };
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div>Getting Started with AJAX using JAVA: Hello World!</div>
<div id="hello"><button type="button" onclick="makeRequest()">Say Hello!</button></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To run a servlet program you need to make an HTTP request to a web server that is configured to execute the servlet.

Your Ajax URL (as displayed in the error message) starts with `file://` so you are trying to deal with a local file instead of a webserver.

Install a webserver (such as Tomcat). Load your HTML document from it. Make sure that `"HelloWorld"` is a relative URI from that HTML document to the servlet URL.